# Finding parameters a and b

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-ax-b\right) =0
$$
Find a and b so the limit is equal to zero

Comment: Clearly $a=1$....

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: Given the edit, I feel the need to clarify. It is not the lack of an actual question that spurred my downvote -- it is (the illusion of) dumping problems to the website without any apparent effort of your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write as a single fraction:

\begin{align}
\frac{x^2 + 1}{x + 1} - ax - b =&\ \frac{x^2+1 - ax(x + 1) - b(x + 1)}{x + 1} \\
=&\ \frac{x^2 + 1 - ax^2 - ax - bx - b}{x + 1} \\
=&\ \frac{(1 - a)x^2 + (-a - b)x + (1 - b)}{x + 1} 
\end{align}

Choose $a$ and $b$ such that there is no $x^2$ term and no $x$ term, i.e. the coefficient of the $x^2$ term is $0$ and the coefficient of the $x$ term is $0$.  Then the limit will go to zero because you'll have a constant over $x + 1$ which goes to $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Write

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}=\frac{(x+1)^2-2(x+1)+2}{x+1}=(x-1)+\frac{2}{x+1}$$

Comment: I don't really see the intuition here...if you want to do polynomial long division then do it.  But that's not really what you appear to have did even though it's the final result.

Comment: @Jared  Jared, the intuition is to effectively enforce a substitution $x\to x+1$.  And your comment "if you want to do polynomial long division then do it," is offensive.

Comment: I see it now...although I'm not sure how obvious it is why you have to have $-2(x + 1)+2$ (i.e. _why_ is this necessary and _how_ did you find it).  I apologize if what I said was offensive.  It just seemed to me that you were doing polynomial long division (which is basically what you're doing) and now I see it's just in a different way--an interesting way though.

Comment: @Jared No worry.  We're friends on here.  Here's one way forward.  Write $x^2+1=(x+1-1)^2+1=(x+1)^2-2(x+1)+2$.  Then, divide.  That is the method.  It is effectively substituting $x\to x+1$. -Mark

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$\frac{x^2 + 1}{x + 1} - ax - b
=\frac{x^2 }{x + 1}+\frac{ 1}{x + 1} - ax - b
$.
Since
$\frac{ 1}{x + 1}
\to 0
$,
we can ignore this term
and just look at
$\frac{x^2 }{x + 1} - ax - b
=\frac{x^2-(ax+b)(x+1) }{x + 1}
=\frac{x^2(1-a)-x(a+b)+b }{x + 1}
$.

To make this $\to 0$,
we naturally get
the same equayions
as before:
$1-a = 0, a+b = 0$.